# Query Find next element From ¢this which has an id equal to

Tags: jquery, find

I wish to be able to process the following.

Within the Dom I want find all elements where the id contains "startDateTimeInputHidden".
This I'm determining as my starting point ¢(this).
I want to then find the next element where the id equals to 'startdate' then set the value to the value found in "startDateTimeInputHidden".

Here is what I've been trying

```
                $jq("input[id*='startDateTimeInputHidden']").each(function() {
                    var currentValue = $jq("input[id*='startDateTimeInputHidden']").val();
                 $jq(this).nextUntil("input[id*='startdate']").val(currentValue));
```

I must be using nextUntil incorrectly as it breaks my jquery. Can anyone spot what I'm doing incorrectly or know of a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Hard to help troubleshoot a traverse of html we can't see

Comment: Hi charlietfl,  I think I may be using the wrong function but I'm not sure

Comment: $jq("input[id*='startDateTimeInputHidden']").each(function() {
                      alert('found me');
                      var currentValue = $jq("input[id*='startDateTimeInputHidden']").val();
                      alert('found me2 ' + currentValue);
                       $jq(this).nextUntil("#testNext").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
                     });

Comment: <div class="form-element__control">
   <span class="text-body_small">Start:</span> 
   <span>
      <div>
       <input id="startDateTimeInputHidden" size="20" type="text" value="1/1/2018 9:00 PM"/>
      </div>
      <div><input id="testNext" type="text"/></div>
   </span>
</div>

Comment: This is just an example. Basically I want to find the next element with id 'testNext" from the current position I am in my each loop.

I think nextAll() may not be the most apt function.

Any tips are welcomed.  Thanks,

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, I was not sure how to add all my content in one comment as I was over the character limit.